# Google Checkout ship-items order status notification

Tags: c#, google-checkout

I am currently implementing GC into my project. I am posting and receiving orders fine. What i'm having problems with now is trying to POST to GC to update an order status to delivered.

I would like to implement this:

```
_type=ship-items
&google-order-number=ORDER_NUMBER
&item-shipping-information-list.item-shipping-information-1.item-id.merchant-item-id=A1
&item-shipping-information-list.item-shipping-information-1.tracking-data-list.tracking-data-1.carrier=UPS
&item-shipping-information-list.item-shipping-information-1.tracking-data-list.tracking-data-1.tracking-number=5555AbCd
&send-email=true
```

as can be seen here: https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API_Line_Item_Shipping#Ship_Items

What I don't understand is how to send the information to GC

I am using the following form to send my cart information which works fine:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/api/checkout/v2/checkoutForm/Merchant/MERCHANT_ID" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="PRODUCT_NAME" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_description_1" value="PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_quantity_1" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_price_1" value="20.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_currency_1" value="GMP" />
</form>
```

Is this the way I should be sending the delivery notification?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at the Checkout Order Processing API.

Some docs below:

https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Processing#order_processing_api

http://support.google.com/checkout/sell/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=25397

Also look at the Checkout client libraries sample code:

https://developers.google.com/checkout/samplecode